# What does the Diatessaron have to say about the reading of Matthew 28:19?

Tags: matthew, textual-criticism

As you probably know, George Howard's *Hebrew Gospel of Matthew* 28:19 only has the word "Go" and a Coptic manuscript also supports this reading.

See Budge, E. A. Wallis. Coptic Texts, Volume V: Miscellaneous Coptic Texts . . . London: Museum, 1915, p. 637.

I believe a better wording of that text would be "Go to them".

Comment: I would like to know your concern about whether it should have been "Go to them" ... "Go" by itself would have been clear as it's followed by "to all nations" meaning "them". This has to do with how people wrote in the past .

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that any manuscripts are available of the Syriac original of Tatian's *Diatessaron* (although there now appears to be a translation of Ephraim's Syriac commentary available).  Based on the [available translations](http://www.ccel.org/ccel/schaff/anf09.iv.html), however, I am not sure we can find support for the first part of Matthew 28:19.  The *Diatessaron* borrows from John and Mark for §55:5 and skips to Matthew 28:19b in §55:6:

> 5 *Go now into all the world, and preach my gospel in all the
>   creation* [John 20:21b, Mark 16:15b];
>
> 6 *and teach all the peoples, and baptize them in the name of the
>   Father and the Son and the Holy Spirit; and teach them to keep all
>   whatsoever I commanded you* [Matthew 28:19b]